# is this time to remove the databases from the availability group? which ones?

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, transaction-log, transactional-replication, high-availability

While [patching one of my servers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/219265/22336) that is part of an availability group,
as a secondary, I had [some problems](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219206/when-applying-a-sql-server-cumulative-update-or-service-pack-on-a-virtual-machin)  - the real problem was that the host machine of one of the virtual servers in the availability group - run out of disk space for a brief minute or two.

It does not matter what was the problem, for this question.

The facts are:

1. I had 2 machines on the availability group, lost the secondary.
2. The availability group was involved in replication and [I was getting the following error message](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76940c2b-8b3a-48e2-9314-0aaa947e150d/replicated-transactions-are-waiting-for-next-log-backup-or-for-mirroring-partner-to-catch-up):

> Replicated transactions are waiting for next Log backup or for
>   mirroring partner to catch up

which was solved by starting the following trace flag:

```
DBCC TRACEON(1448,-1)
```

3. I find some info about my availability group, and I can see one server is down according to the scripts below:

   select * from sys.dm_hadr_cluster_members

[image]

```
SELECT
gs.primary_replica as 'Primary Server',
DB_NAME(dd.database_id) as 'Database Name',
secondary_recovery_health_desc as 'Secondary Server Health Status',
synchronization_state_desc as 'Synchronization State',
database_state_desc as 'Database State',
--suspend_reason_desc as 'Suspended Reason',
--last_sent_time as 'Last Data Send Time',
--last_received_time as 'Last Data Received TIme',
--last_hardened_time as 'Last Hardened Time',
--last_redone_time as 'Last Redone Time',
--log_send_queue_size as 'Log Send Queue Size',
--log_send_rate as 'Log Send Rate',
--redo_queue_size as 'Redo Queue Size',
--redo_rate as 'Rate of Redo',
--filestream_send_rate as 'Filestream Send Rate',
last_commit_time as 'Last Commit Time',
low_water_mark_for_ghosts as 'Low Water Mark for Ghosts'
FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states as gs
left outer JOIN sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states as dd ON gs.group_id = dd.group_id
ORDER BY gs.primary_replica DESC, DB_NAME(dd.database_id) DESC
```

[image]

The always On script [at this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164406/dba-first-day-in-a-new-job-check-backups-and-security-how-what-else-should) does not tell me much either

QUESTION:

How much far behind am I in the transaction log, catching up with a replica that will never come back?

I need information to solve this question:

Should I remove the databases from the availability group?

or should I build a new server, add it to the availability group, wait for the logs to catch up?

Comment: In regard to how far behind where catching up isn't possible - it is different for each environment and workload. If you have historical stats on send rate and redo rate then we can do some easy math, otherwise it's a best guess kind of situation :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to remove the databases from the availability group, on this occasion.
for this I have used the following scripts:

```
-- https://blog.pythian.com/list-of-sql-server-databases-in-an-availability-group/
-- How do we know that this instance is part of Availability Group(s):
SELECT
AG.name AS [Name],
ISNULL(agstates.primary_replica, '') AS [PrimaryReplicaServerName],
ISNULL(arstates.role, 3) AS [LocalReplicaRole]
FROM master.sys.availability_groups AS AG
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states as agstates
    ON AG.group_id = agstates.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.availability_replicas AS AR
    ON AG.group_id = AR.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS arstates
    ON AR.replica_id = arstates.replica_id AND arstates.is_local = 1
ORDER BY [Name] ASC

-- https://blog.pythian.com/list-of-sql-server-databases-in-an-availability-group/
-- How do we get some information about the databases in the Availability Group:
SELECT
AG.name AS [AvailabilityGroupName],
ISNULL(agstates.primary_replica, '') AS [PrimaryReplicaServerName],
ISNULL(arstates.role, 3) AS [LocalReplicaRole],
dbcs.database_name AS [DatabaseName],
ISNULL(dbrs.synchronization_state, 0) AS [SynchronizationState],
ISNULL(dbrs.is_suspended, 0) AS [IsSuspended],
ISNULL(dbcs.is_database_joined, 0) AS [IsJoined],
remove_database='USE [master]' + char(13) + 'ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP ' + quotename(AG.name ) + char(13) + 'REMOVE DATABASE ' + quotename(dbcs.database_name) + char(13)
FROM master.sys.availability_groups AS AG
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states as agstates
   ON AG.group_id = agstates.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.availability_replicas AS AR
   ON AG.group_id = AR.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS arstates
   ON AR.replica_id = arstates.replica_id AND arstates.is_local = 1
INNER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states AS dbcs
   ON arstates.replica_id = dbcs.replica_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states AS dbrs
   ON dbcs.replica_id = dbrs.replica_id AND dbcs.group_database_id = dbrs.group_database_id
ORDER BY AG.name ASC, dbcs.database_name
```